# Invalid Salt on Local versus Heroku (Encoding UTF-8 problems)

Tags: python, heroku, flask, utf-8, bcrypt

**The Issue:**

It appears there is some sort of encoding/decoding issue going on with flask-bcrypt for my Mac.  I'd like to know if there is an easy solution to fix this so I can run my local with a similar setup to my Heroku version.

**Comparison:**

*Local*

- If I use .decode("utf-8") with generate_password_hash it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.` Without decode, it saves my password to the database properly and I'm able to login with no issues.
- When I test bcrypt.generate_password_hash [without decode] in terminal on local it
  returns like '$2b$12$yTBsCi.....`

*Heroku*

- If I use .decode("utf-8") with generate_password_hash it saves to the database properly and I"m able to login.  If I don't use decode("utf-8"), it saves the password incorrectly (something like:   `\x243261243132245a4e64696e4d7062327......`) and when I try to login it returns `ValueError: Invalid salt`.
- When I test bcrypt.generate_password_hash [without decode] on heroku bash it returns
  b'$2b$12$amVQ6f2.d......'

**Current Setup:**

Both are running Python 3.6.4.  Both Heroku and my local version have identical requirements installed.  `bcrypt==3.1.4`  `Flask-bcrypt==0.7.1` `py-bcrypt==0.4`

**Documentation:**

https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> In Python 3, you need to use decode(‘utf-8’) on generate_password_hash(), like below:
>   `pw_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(‘hunter2’).decode(‘utf-8’)`

**Final Thoughts:**

Any solutions to get my Mac encoding/decoding correctly?  Perhaps because MacOS relies on Python 2.7 it's messing it up?  But this shouldn't be the case within my virtualenv.....

I've run `echo $LANG` and looked at the psql server_encoding on local/heroku and they are both identical for utf8.

Comment: I will say this made it very challenging to even figure out .decode was the fix I needed on heroku.  It took me forever to just try .decode('utf-8') on Heroku because it was failing on my local.  Now it's making it difficult to develop on local because I keep having to take off the .decode('utf-8') before I run it and put it back on before I push it back to heroku.

Comment: Still not sure on this one.  No luck in figure it out.  I've tried changing some Mac settings so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So!  This is a mind boggling problem for a lot of people.  Now that I have found a solution, I'm back to post the results.

- **Solution Part A:**  [The most important piece is in Solution Part B, this is a minor fix]. The first thing I realized was that I was using double quotes around my utf-8.  I then rechecked the documentation and realized it was a single quote `.decode('utf-8')`.  As soon as I did this, it seemed to fix the problem (at least temporarily).  Why that fixes it, I'm uncertain, but that's something to try and a small detail to overlook.  After a few days of more pushes, the bug popped back up.
- **Solution Part B:** This is the much larger problem that I learned.  After hours of searching I stumbled on a google search that was something along the lines of "Flask-bcrypt py-bcrypt conflict".  There were some ambiguous stack overflow questions and github issues that lead me to realize there was likely something conflicting between these packages.  So naturally I removed them an reinstalled py-bcrypt, flask-bcrypt, and bcrypt.  Same problem.  Then I did it again in a different order....new problem....about ffi being missing.  So then I uninstalled all of them and ONLY installed flask-bcrypt.  Well wouldn't you know...that fixed the problem for Heroku and my local.  It turns out that when you install flask-bcrypt it auto installs bcrypt.  I left py-bcrypt uninstalled entirely.  It seems bcrypt and py-crypt really don't like each other.

Hope that fixes it for you!

(note: I do have this feeling that bcrypt is still accessing py-bcrypt in some way, maybe through headers or the python package itself.  Regardless, removing it from my virtual environment did the trick).

(alternative solution: I heard if these packages just really don't play nice, you can use generate_password_hash from something like werkzeug or try installing the cryptography package.  I didn't want to go that route though, but worth a shot).